# webgrid sort indicator, asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want a sort indicator as image for ascending and descending for webgrid columns. I did google search and found the solution as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('thead > tr > th > a[href*="sort=@grid.SortColumn"]').parent()
.append('@(grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "U" : "D")');
</script>

 But i used the webgrid like this:

 var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage:       SlmgWebApp.Controllers.HomeController.PageSize, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", fieldNamePrefix: "ViewClaimfieldname", pageFieldName: "ViewClaimpagename");



grid.Bind(Model.TotalClaims, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);



@grid.GetHtml(

 tableStyle: "webgrid",
 headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
 footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
 alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
 selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",

    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    columns: grid.Columns(
             grid.Column("", header: "", format: @<span><img alt="image1" src="@item.StatusIcon" title="@item.StatusName" style="height:25px; width:25px; border:0px" /></span>),

                    grid.Column("CustomerName", header: "Reference"),

                         grid.Column("RepairOrderNumber", header: "Repair Order"),

                        grid.Column("SlmgReferenceNumber", header: "SLMG Number", format: @<text><a href="javascript: getclaim('@item.SlmgReferenceNumber')">@item.SlmgReferenceNumber</a></text>),

                                  grid.Column("EquipmentManfacturer", header: "Warranty Provider"),

                                 grid.Column("SerialNumber", header: "Serial Number (P&A Number)")



                                  ));
```

}

if i am placing the javascript function in page load it is throwing error that the grid has not loaded.  And i had given an ajax call for data loading this webgrid.  Could any one help me where i have to place this javascript so that i could get an indicator for sorting columns in webgrid.

Comment: i dont know what happened to my comment, by improving your ccept rate i meant to accept the answers you hav got on your previous questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the java script into the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('thead > tr > th > a[href*="sort=@grid.SortColumn"]').parent().append('@(grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "U" : "D")');
 });
```

Far bit of warning -- this method doesn't work with ajax updatable grid. (which is what i am trying to figure out as well)